# make a variable inaccessible in a certain scope, possible?

Tags: c++, scope

Is there a way to disable all access to a variable in a certain scope?

Its usage might be similar to this :-

```
int outerOnly=5; //primitive or class or struct, it can also be a field
outerOnly=4;  //ok
{//vvv The disable command may be in a block?
    disable outerOnly; //<--- I want some thing like this.
    outerOnly=4; //should compile error (may be assert fail?)
    int c=outerOnly;  //should compile error
}
outerOnly=4;  //ok
```

If the answer is no, is there any feature closest to this one?

It would be useful in a few situation of debugging.
**Edit:** For example, I know for sure that a certain scope (also too unique to be a function) should never access a single certain variable.

Comment: No, you cannot do anything like that and I'm not sure there is anything like it. Can't really see any help in debugging since breakpoints and logging would already probably give the needed information

Comment: The closest thing you can do is move that inner block to its own function (though globals are still accessible).

Comment: *"It would be useful in a few situation of debugging."* - I don't think so.

Comment: *"For example, I know for sure that a certain scope (also too unique to be a function) should never access a single certain variable."* - If your code is so complex that you think that such a terrible hack would be useful, then please refactor your code such that variables don't accidentally appear in wrong scopes without causing compilation errors. And what exactly is "too unique to be a function"?

Comment: @Christian Hackl   "too unique to be a function" = If it becomes a function, it will be called only 1 time.  This function may also need to access some local variables of caller, so I will have to pass them manually.   Thus, IMHO, I think it is not so appropriate to make it a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider implementing something like this (perhaps with deleted copy constructors and assignment operators):

```
struct disable
{
private:
    disable(const disable&) = delete;
    disable& operator=(const disable&) = delete;
public:
    disable() {}
};
```

Then, placing

```
disable outerOnly;
```

inside the inner scope would result pretty much in the desired errors.

Keep in mind though, as **@Cornstalks** commented, that it may lead to shadowing-related compiler warnings (which, in turn, can usually be disabled on case by case basis).

Comment: Note that this may cause warnings with shadow definitions, depending on your compiler settings.

Comment: Thank AlexD. +1   Is it also possible to avoid the warning (mentioned by Cornstalks) from compiler?

Comment: I'd recommend a macro for a bit of conditional compilation. `#define DISABLE(var) disable var;` Will at least allow a warning free build given the right `-D` option.

Comment: What is "can usually be disabled on case by case basis"?  Do you mean - line by line?  How?  I am new for C++.

Comment: @javaLover You can have a macro which will (1) save settings; (2) disable concrete warning; (3) do `disable(var)`; (4) enable settings back. This way you do not need disable the warning, which might be useful in other cases, completely. Look at `#pragma`s for your compiler.

Comment: @Cornstalks Thanks! I added it to the post.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to disable all access to a variable in a certain scope?

No, there is no such feature.

> If the answer is no, is there any feature closest to this one?

Instead of a simple block, you could define and call a closure that doesn't capture the undesired variable:

```
int outerOnly;
int innerToo;
[&innerToo]()
{
    innerToo  = 42;        // ok
    outerOnly = 4;         // fails to compile
    int c     = outerOnly; // fails to compile
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a `struct Outeronly;`.

Note that the error messages can be perplexing if one is unfamiliar with them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pretty straightforward solution:

```
int main()
{
        int outerOnly=5; //primitive or class or struct, it can also be a field
        outerOnly=4;  //ok
        #define outerOnly outerOnly_disabled
        //outerOnly=4; //error outerOnly_disabled is not declared
        //int c=outerOnly;  //error 
        #undef outerOnly

        outerOnly=4;  //ok
}
```